# How do I find the equation for estimated ratios, 1700:13, 1275:7, 450:3?

Tags: linear-algebra, exponential-function, ratio

In the game SCP: Secret Laboratory, there's an enemy character called SCP-049 who can kill players and then resurrect them after a set number of seconds. These are the times that I've plotted out so far:

```
SCP-049 Health | Seconds until resurrection is complete
1700 hp        | 13 seconds
1550 hp        | 11 seconds
1275 hp        | 7 seconds
 850 hp        | 4 seconds
 450 hp        | 2 seconds
   1 hp        | 1 second
```

The seconds aren't perfect because I had to time them in my head instead of objectively with a timer.

It seems to be exponential and not linear. I've tried writing out an equation on a piece of paper but I wasn't able to figure it out.

How can I create a rough equation that's close enough to these ratios to be replicated?

Comment: I ploted the points and they seem to be logarithmic

Comment: You can type them into a spreadsheet and ask it to find the trendline.  You can choose exponential or logarithmic fits depending on which variable you put on the horizontal axis.  There is a whole area of numerical analysis called data fitting.  Any text will have a chapter or more.  You might want to ignore the point at 1hp because it is hard to time that and doesn't seem to fit the curve

Comment: Plotting the points, it seems that $(450,3)$ is an anomaly.

Comment: @AopsVol.2, ah, logarithm! I completely forgot about those :) Just realized it's been a decade since my discrete mathematics class.

Comment: @TobyMak It's somewhere between 2-3 seconds but I can't time it in my head. I changed it to 2 so that it's more accurate.

Comment: From the graph it seems like the time to reach 450 HP is around $2.3$ seconds. It might be you mistimed that point particularly badly, so if you want a more accurate fit, you probably need to retime that point.

Comment: I haven't forgotten about this issue, I just haven't had the time to code it into my C# program yet! Hopefully I'll accept an answer before the end of the year.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple quadratic or exponential work find:

[image]

Comment: The $R^2$ coefficient of the quadratic fit is $0.986$, which is pretty good!

Comment: Thank you! Let me plug some HP values into the equation and see if it corresponds.

Answer (score 3):

Based on the power model
$$y=a +b\,x^c$$ we can find (using nonlinear regression)
$$a=1.20472 \qquad b=8.0561\times 10^{-7} \qquad c=2.21806$$ and this corresponds to $R^2=0.998985$ and $SSQ=0.365$.
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
x & y & y_{calc} \\
 1700 & 13 & 12.9928 \\
 1550 & 11 & 10.8089 \\
 1275 & 7 & 7.43234 \\
 850 & 4 & 3.73834 \\
 450 & 2 & 1.82288 \\
 1 & 1 & 1.20472
\end{array}
\right)$$

Based on the exponential model
$$y=a+b\, e^{c x}$$
$$a=-0.425564 \qquad b=1.37329 \qquad c=1.34804\times 10^{-3}$$ and this corresponds to $R^2=0.999416$ and $SSQ=0.210$ (better than the previous one).

$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
x & y & y_{calc} \\
 1700 & 13 & 13.1582 \\
 1550 & 11 & 10.6714 \\
 1275 & 7 & 7.23402 \\
 850 & 4 & 3.89352 \\
 450 & 2 & 2.09335 \\
 1 & 1 & 0.94958
\end{array}
\right)$$

Comment: I'll be honest, this is way over my head. I basically need to input the HP into a C# function and get the seconds back. Would that be `return Math.Pow(hp, 2.21806) * 0.0080561 + 1.20472`?

Comment: I have no idea what the `e` and the `cx` means in the second equation.

Comment: @PatPeter. Read if as $y=a+b\, \exp(c\times x)$

Comment: For those that do not know, 'SSQ' is an abbreviation for 'total sum of squares'.

Answer (score 2):

I tried a parabola
$$
f(x) = 4.152249135\times 10^{-6} x^2+1.00000000
$$

[image: parabola]

Answer (score 1):

An exponential fit seems close

[image]

Comment: exactly what i was getting to :). But wouldn't seconds be the independent variable making it be logarithmic?

Comment: No, the health is what changes, so it is the independent variable. The time passed until resurrection depends on how much health the character has.

Comment: You're right, im so used to putting seconds on the x-axis :) brings up memories of 6th-grade science class.

Comment: @AopsVol.2:  this looks like an invertible function, so you can plot it either way around you like.  From $y=ae^{bx}$ we get $x=\frac {\log(y)-\log(a)}b$  The quadratic that David G. Stork found can be inverted over the range $hp \gt 0$

Answer (score 1):

It seems that from the graph, an exponential fit does the job. However, I experimented and found that adding a linear term increased the correlation:

[image]

$$y = 1.00144^x + 9.20443 \cdot 10^{-4}$$
$$R^2 = 0.9932$$

From the graph it seems like $(450,3)$ is an anomaly. However, if you measure that point again and it comes up with a similar result, then you can add a quadratic term to make that point fit:

$$y = 1.00164^x + 2.36515 \cdot 10^{-3}x - 2.42192 \cdot 10^{-6} x^2$$
$$R^2 = 0.9955$$

Comment: Yeah they were all done with manual counting, not with a stopwatch or anything, so it probably was off. Thank you for the answer!

Comment: No problem! Forgot I had even written this answer haha.